# Finding the marginal densities of uniformly distributed X, Y

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

If (X, Y) is uniformly distributed over the region defined by $$ 0 ≤ y ≤ 1−x^{2} $$ and $$ −1 ≤ x ≤1 $$, what would the marginal densities of X and Y be? I have determined that, for X: $$ f_{x}(x) = \int_{0}^{1 - x^{2}}f(x,y)dy $$. But how do I find f(x, y) is? It is not given in the question.

Comment: What do you think they mean when they say that something is uniformly distributed?

Answer (score 1):

When the question says "X,Y are uniformly distributed over the region"

$ 0 \; {\le} \;  Y {\le} \; 1-x^2 $ and

$ -1 \: {\le} \; X \: {\le} \; 1 $

what the question is really trying to say is that over the region the joint density, $f(x,y) $ is just a constant. That is, the joint density is just some number c over this region.

Thus, what do you know about all probability densities? You should know that they must integrate to one. Thus, using some sort of double integration expression over the given region, we can easily find c such that $f(x,y)$ is a legitimate probability density. You may find drawing the region helpful.

In this case, we have

$ c \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x^2} dydx = 1 $

Solve for c to get the joint density, and then you can find your marginal distributions from there.